# PowerShell - Remove-ADGroup not allowing pipe-in from Get-ADGroup -filter

Tags: powershell

I have the following line of code, which is supposed to get all Active Directory groups beginning with the @ symbol and then remove a user from those groups;

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter 'name -like "@*"' | Remove-ADGroup -identity [USERID]
```

Get-ADGroup works great, it successfully grabs all of the groups beginning with @, however I get the following error for each and every @ group when piped through to Remove-ADGroup;

```
Remove-ADGroup : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
At line:1 char:41
+ Get-ADGroup -Filter 'name -like "@*"' | Remove-ADGroup -identity [USERID]
+                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: CN=@Workplace,O...ife,DC=co,DC=uk:PSObject) [Remove-ADGroup], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.RemoveADGroup
```

I can't figure out why the pipe won't work.

Comment: That's why you should always use `-WhatIf` with `Remove-` cmdlets until you're 100% sure what you're doing is correct and working.. This could have gone very wrong. :-)

Comment: Very good point! Thank you for pointing this out, I'm quite new to PowerShell (as you can probably tell), so I'll keep this in mind from now on!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Remove-ADGroup` will **remove the group entirely** - this is definitely not what you want.

Use [`Remove-ADGroupMember`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617242.aspx) instead:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter 'name -like "@*"' | Remove-ADGroupMember -Members [USERID]
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you.

Comment: Just going to confirm actually, if the output of -whatif for the above is "What if: Performing operation "Set" on Target "CN=@[GROUP NAME]OU=[OU DETAILS]", does this seem OK?

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately it's not more specific. Some cmdlet have more meaningful messages, but at least it says Set-operation (modify) on the group which is correct. If you're unsure, run the command on a single group to test the first time. `get-adgroup mytestgroup | Remove-adgroupmember -members someuser`